# Understanding the proof of the following statement: $2$ elements $g,h$ of a group $G$ are conjugates $\implies \exists a,b \in G$ s.t. $g=ab, h=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Understanding the proof of the following statement: $2$ elements $g,h$ of a group $G$ are conjugates $\implies \exists a,b \in G$ s.t. $g=ab, h=ba$

It goes like this: $g,h$ conjugates $\implies \exists k \in G$ s.t. $g=khk^{-1}$

Now if $b=k, a= k^{-1}h$

$g =k^{-1}hk = ab$, and $h=kgk^{-1} = ba$

What I don't understand is why $h=kgk^{-1} = ba$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $g=khk^{-1}$ is equivalent to $k^{-1}gk=h$, and not to $h=kgk^{-1}$.
To see this, multiply by $k^{-1}$ from the left, and by $k$ from the right:
\begin{align}
g & = khk^{-1}, \\
k^{-1}g k & = (k^{-1}k) h(k^{-1}k)=h.
\end{align}

If we have $g=khk^{-1}$, and $a=hk^{-1}$, $b=k$, then of course $ab=hk^{-1}k=h$.

Comment: i'm  sorry i still don't see how if $ g=khk^{-1}=ba$ then $h=k^{-1}gk=ab$

Comment: say $b=k$ and $a=k^{-a}h$ Then we have $g=khk^{-1} = ba$ and $h= k^{-1}gk = k^{-1}gb$ but i can't go any further

Comment: If you have $a=hk^{-1}$ and $b=k$, then of course $ab=hk^{-1}\cdot k=h\cdot (k^{-1}k)=h\cdot e=h$.